# Boost mpl - append an element for each element in a vector

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-mpl

I have a boost mpl vector with types in it (obviously). I want to, after declaring this vector, iterate over it and append each type, wrapped in another template, to that vector. I have tried many things but for the life of me I can't figure this one out. I'm not sure if it's even possible to change an mpl vector when iterating over it, like, does iterator invalidation work the same as in the STL? Basically, what I have is this:

```
typedef boost::mpl::vector<int, float, double> MyTypes;
template<typename T> struct wrapper { T _value; };
```

and then I want to add `wrapper<int>`, `wrapper<float>` and `wrapper<double>` to MyTypes. Of course in my real code I have many more types that I don't want to duplicate.

So I'm thinking this should be possible, like by combining boost::mpl::fold with boost::mpl::back_inserter in some way, but I can't figure it out... Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what  exactly you mean by "changing a type" in C++. Types are not variables, they cannot be changed. You can only create a new type.

Comment: I'm looking for the functional equivalent of what I described, so it's OK if the first vector of types is one type, then some algorithm is applied to it that creates a second vector with the wrapped types, and then in a third step the two are joined into one again.

Comment: Then you are probably looking for `boost::mpl::transform` and `boost::mpl::joint_view`.